# Optimizing program execution by binding the process to a core

Tags: process, ubuntu-14.04

I have a c program which does number crunching - no disk access, etc. I am running, simultaneously,  different versions of this on an 8 core Ubuntu 14.x machine. I want to optimize its performance by binding the processes to individual cores.

I have done the following:

o Edited /etc/default/grub and added isolcpus=0,1,2,3,4,5 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

o Ran update-grub

o Rebooted

After reboot, /proc/cmdline has the new isolcpus phrase

I then ran a script with a short test c program (all identical) using commands

```
taskset -c 0 tcsh -c '( time ./testx ) > & test_out0 ' &
taskset -c 1 tcsh -c '( time ./testx ) > & test_out1 ' &
taskset -c 2 tcsh -c '( time ./testx ) > & test_out2 ' &
taskset -c 3 tcsh -c '( time ./testx ) > & test_out3 ' &
taskset -c 4 tcsh -c '( time ./testx ) > & test_out4 ' &
taskset -c 5 tcsh -c '( time ./testx ) > & test_out5 ' &
```

top command shows that the processes use the first 6 cores with near or at 100% utilization as expected

What I do not understand is, the programs run with significantly different elapsed times. (The fact that processes on some cores are lagging is also apparent in the top command display.) In any case, the consecutive outputs generated by the above statements look like:

```
100.824u 0.096s 1:40.80 100.1%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
101.020u 0.000s 1:40.93 100.0%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
78.472u 0.000s 1:18.37 100.1%   0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
78.628u 0.000s 1:18.52 100.1%   0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
100.992u 0.004s 1:40.86 100.1%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
101.116u 0.000s 1:40.98 100.1%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

So, a big range from 78.472 seconds to 101.02 seconds. If I run the test again, the performance of the cores match their previous performances. And amazingly, the average of the times come very close to the average when I ran the program without binding the processes to the cores.

I am probably missing a significant point in understanding optimization based on binding cores to processes. I will appreciate any help in solving this problem.

Regards, MCY.